# Gambling question: multiply quotes.

Tags: probability, arithmetic

Reading various betting forum I came across different threads claiming ***betting multiple is worse than betting on single events***.

Could you explain why?

[Clairification for the ones not familiar with betting:
Betting on a single event: predict the outcome of a single match.
Betting on multiple events: predict the outcome of multiple matches, you win only if you guess correctly the outcome of all the events, even if you only make one mistake you win nothing.]

I think that the key point is the commission taken by bookmakers on each match (they take something like 5% on every bet).

For example if you bet 100dollars on a tennis match where each player has P(win) = 0.5, You will win something like 195 instead of 200, due to commissions.

Comment: Part of might also do with fact that probability you will win multiple event is usually smaller than single. For example if you bet on single event that has 0.0001 probability of winning this May seem quite low but even if you go bet on 4 events that each have 0.05 probability of winning and assuming wins are independent of each other, then you have a probability of winning $0.05^{4}=0.00000625<0.0001$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the outcomes of all the matches are independent, with $p_k$ being the probability of a favorable outcome of the $k^{th}$ match, for matches numbered $1$ to $n$.  Then probability of favourable outcomes occurring in all matched will be:$$P_{\text{all}}=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n p_k$$

Since $0\leq p_j\leq 1$ for all $j$, then it follows that: $p_k\geq \prod\limits_{j=1}^n p_j$ for all k.

Comment: Which means in common language? :)

Comment: @TomDwan Since no individual probability can be greater than one, then the product of all of them cannot be greater than the least of them.

Comment: It pretty much means the given any number of multiple events you can bet on the probability of winning will always be greater if betted on one of them individually

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're wrong. Betting on multiple events is worse. This happens because of the commissions. I will try to explain it with numbers and not with formulas, because it's easier to be understood.

Assume you want to bet on 2 events with P(win)=0.5. Initially you have €100.

**Case 1: No commissions:**

**Case 1a**: Betting on single events:

1st event: You bet €100. You win. You win €100. You get €100.You have €200

2nt event: You bet €200. You win. You win €200. You get €200.You have €400

**Case 1b**: Betting on multiple events:

You bet €100. You win. You win €300. You get €300. You have €400.

The result is the same.

**Case 2: With commissions:** (assuming commission is 5%)

First of all, you have to know that the commissions are a percentage of your **winnings**. This means if you bet €1000 and you win €10, you will be charged the same as if you had bet €1 and you had won €10.

**Case 2a**: Bettins on single events:

1st event: You bet €100. You win. You win €100. Commission is 100*0.05=€5.You get €95. You have €195.

2st event: You bet €195. You win. You win €195. Commission is 195*0.05=€9,75.You get €185,25. You have €380,25.

**Case 2b**: Betting on multiple events:

You bet €100. You win. You win €300. Commission is 300*0.05=€15.You get €285. You have €385.

Comment: I like this answer, but it seems to me you're proving that betting single events is worse than multiples. Not the opposite.

Comment: Well, yes. :) This is the truth however. I'll just change my first sentence